# Jquery dialog not working in masterpage?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, updatepanel, master-pages, updateprogress

I added below code in the masterpage. I am able to get `alert("I am in onload Function");`, but jQuery("uploadPic").dialog not working. The `<div>` portion showing on the page.

I am using reference to jQuery is

`<script type=text/javascript src="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.4.4.min.js"></script>`

I tried `$('#uploadPic').dialog` also. But did not work.

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    _spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("onloadFunction");
    function onloadFunction() {
        alert("I am in onload Function");
        //setup edit person dialog
        jQuery("uploadPic").dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            modal: true,
            height: 375,
            width: 400,
            draggable: true,
            title: "Upload Picture",
            open: function (type, data) {
                $(this).parent().appendTo("form");
            }
        });
    }
    function showDialog(id) {
        alert("Hi");
        $('#' + id).dialog("open");
        alert("End");
    }
</script>

<map name="Map">
        <area shape="rect" coords="225,16,287,33" href="/_layouts/MyAlerts.aspx"  onclick="javascript:showDialog('uploadPic');"  alt="My Alerts">
     </map>
<div id='uploadPic'>        
      <table  class="ms-authoringcontrols"  style="border-top:1px black solid; border:1px black solid; height:70px "  >
    <tbody>
    <tr>
         <td class="ms-sectionheader ms-rightAlign">
        Please choose a picture to upload to your picture library.
          </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: You mention you've included jQuery, but have you also included jQuery UI to get access to the .dialog() function? If so, are you getting any errors in the console?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On top of not referencing jQuery in a `<script>` element, and not referenceing jQuery UI in a `<script>` element, and not linking to some jQuery UI css in a `<link>` element, and not using an octothorpe `#` when selecting by id `jQuery("#uploadPic)`, you also never call your `showDialog(...)` function:

```
function showDialog(id) {
    alert("Hi");
    $('#' + id).dialog("open");
    alert("End");
}
```

Since you have specified `autoOpen: false` when you called `dialog({...})`...

```
    jQuery("uploadPic").dialog({
        autoOpen: false, // <---
        modal: true,
        height: 375,
        width: 400,
        draggable: true,
        title: "Upload Picture",
        open: function (type, data) {
            $(this).parent().appendTo("form");
        }
    });
```

... the dialog is not visible at first. You have to call either `open(...)` or `dialog("open")` - like you did in your `showDialog(...)` function.

But since you never call that function, it never opens the dialog.

Try this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>

    <title>Jquery dialog not working in masterpage?</title>
    <script type=text/javascript src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type=text/javascript src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.9/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />

    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
//  _spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("onloadFunction"); // since I'm not using SharePoint I have replaced this line with jQuery(document).ready(...) below

    function onloadFunction() {
        alert("I am in onload Function");
        //setup edit person dialog
        jQuery("#uploadPic").dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            modal: true,
            height: 375,
            width: 400,
            draggable: true,
            title: "Upload Picture",
            open: function (type, data) {
                $(this).parent().appendTo("form");
            }
        });
        jQuery("#open-button").click(function() {
            showDialog("uploadPic");
        });
    }

    function showDialog(id) {
        alert("Hi");
        $('#' + id).dialog("open");
        alert("End");
    }

    $(document).ready(onloadFunction);
    </script>


</head>
<body>

<a id="open-button" style="cursor:pointer;">Open the dialog</a>

<div id='uploadPic'>        
    <table  class="ms-authoringcontrols"  style="border-top:1px black solid; border:1px black solid; height:70px "  >
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td class="ms-sectionheader ms-rightAlign">
                Please choose a picture to upload to your picture library.
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is working.... But When I click .. Page is scrolling to buttom of the page... It should stay at same place

Comment: @James123 - Is that a problem with the example I gave above, or is it a problem when you apply the solutions I describe to your master page? Also, which browser?

Comment: I am using IE9 now. I am using samething like you.$(document).ready.

Comment: @James123 - But are you using `$(document).ready` in your Master Page or is the problem in my example? I don't see any issue with my example.

Comment: @James123 - This still is not what you are actually trying to achieve. Your question is **very** misleading.  The gist of what you said in the comments of my answer was that you want an ajax loading/processing modal that pops up when a page or action takes too long, to let the user know it's processing.  Hence why I sent you on the path of UpdatePanel and UpdateProgress for ASP.NET/MasterPages.  You could do the same thing with `$.ajax` if you like, but I just figured you could learn the .NET route first.  Using a `dialog()` is not the correct way to achieve this affect.

Answer (score 3):

You mention you've included jQuery, but have you also included jQuery UI to get access to the .dialog() function?

Comment: I am not refered to any jQuery UI. Where can i get reference for that?

Comment: should I use jQuery("uploadPic").dialog or $("#uploadPic").dialog. I added UI reference also.

Comment: $("#uploadPic").dialog as you are referencing by ID

Answer (score 3):

You didn't add a reference to jquery ui :

```
<script type=text/javascript src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.9/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

And the line

```
jQuery("uploadPic").dialog({
```

should be

```
jQuery("#uploadPic").dialog({
```

as you're targetting a div with an id.

Comment: <script type=text/javascript src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.11/jquery-ui.min.js"></script> add also. Still not working

Answer (score 1):

I think your immediate problem is that you don't have a # in front of unloadPic in your selector up top, when you are creating the dialog.  It doesn't know what you are trying to select, thus never creates the dialog.

Also, if you are using jQuery, why not attach a click handler for your `dialog()` using jQuery?

```
<map name="Map">
    <area id="myAlerts" 
          shape="rect" 
          coords="225,16,287,33" 
          href="/_layouts/MyAlerts.aspx"
          alt="My Alerts" />
</map>
```

Note that to your `area` tag you need to include an `id`, as well as, add the `/` in front of the `>` to properly close the tag, which you don't have.

This is what I use and I have modified it for your example:

```
(function($, window, document, undefined) {

    // grab dialog and area
    var $dialog = $("#uploadPic"),
        $myAlerts = $("#myAlerts");

    // attach click handler
    $myAlerts.click(function(e) {

        // prevent default click action
        e.preventDefault();        

        // if dialog exists, unbind and open
        if ($dialog.length) $dialog.unbind().dialog('open');

    });

    // added to re-center dialog when window re-sizes
    $(window).resize(function() {

        if ($dialog.length && $dialog.dialog('isOpen'))
            $dialog.dialog('option', 'position', 'center');

    });

})(jQuery, this, document);
```

**EDIT:**

I would also add that since you are using MasterPages, I'd definitely make sure you are adding the `onLoadFunction()` via:

```
if (Sys != undefined && Sys.Application) { 

    // add to Application object
    Sys.Application.add_load(onLoadFunction); 

} else { 

    // fall back to adding to window.onload        
    window.onload = onLoadFunction(); 

}
```

I see the `_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("onloadFunction");`, but I'm not sure what exactly that does.  I would assume it does what it should.

Comment: @James123 - On the unloadPic div? Yes.

Comment: $myAlerts.click is not calling . I added alerts method inside that. doesn't work.

Comment: @James123 - Question ... why are you calling uploadPic dialog and redirecting them to MyAlerts.aspx at the same time via the map/area?

Comment: @James123 - To me, it looks like it would just redirect you to that MyAlerts.aspx page.  We should prevent this action.  I'll edit the click handler.

Comment: MyAlerts.aspx is taking so long to load the page. So I want display a dialog to show "please wait..." kind of dialog.. so user will know... something happening...

Comment: @Scott: Do you have any example to "wait popup" until page loads? catch me @ getur.srikanth@gmail.com

Comment: @James123 - I wouldn't do that through the `dialog()` and furthermore, that's not what the uploadPic div even suggests you are trying to do.  In ASP.NET you can use an [UpdatePanel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.updatepanel.aspx) combined with an [UpdateProgress](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.updateprogress.aspx) to achieve that result.

Comment: @Jame123 - Check out the links in the previous comment.  Plenty of examples in there from Microsoft.

Answer (score -1):

Here is an interesting article using jQuery dialog in asp.net master page.

```
http://deepasp.wordpress.com/2013/05/31/jquery-dialog-in-asp-net-master-page/
```